# nginx Error , keep reopening logs

Tags: nginx

I hope any one can help me or guide me in right direction
recently i moved to a new hosting and started seeing this in my nginx log

```
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6697#0: signal 10 (SIGUSR1) received, reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [info] 6697#0: epoll_wait() failed (4: Interrupted system call)
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6697#0: reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6693#0: signal 10 (SIGUSR1) received, reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6693#0: reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6694#0: signal 10 (SIGUSR1) received, reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [info] 6694#0: epoll_wait() failed (4: Interrupted system call)
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6694#0: reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6695#0: signal 10 (SIGUSR1) received, reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [info] 6695#0: epoll_wait() failed (4: Interrupted system call)
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6695#0: reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6694#0: reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6695#0: reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6696#0: reopening logs
2015/09/24 11:12:01 [notice] 6697#0: reopening logs
```

This was not the case in my old server, both old and new server have same config, same processor and same hdd.
Here is the nginx configure options

```
#  /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.9.3
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) 
configure arguments: --with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-http_perl_module --with-http_flv_module 
--add-module=/usr/local/src/nginx_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.7 
--add-module=/usr/local/src/headers-more-nginx-module-0.261 
--with-debug
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx uses USR1 signal to reopen logs for log rotation purposes, see:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/#Stopping-or-Restarting-Nginx

You should check your logrotate settings, for example in `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx`